# why am I unable to share pdf file to whatsapp from my android app?

Tags: android, whatsapp, mediastore

I am using

```
contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), 
    data.id);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    shareIntent.setType(type); // application/pdf
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    return shareIntent;
```

It is getting shared to WhatsApp, when I choose a contact to share my file, the toast in WhatsApp says: "Sharing failed. Please try again"

It is a device specific issue,
happening in OEM such as Oneplus, Redmi, Oppo
but working fine in Pixel, samsung

Checking whatsapp logs for the issue is:

```
### begin stack trace 2.21.22.26(331416392)
2021-11-30 17:48:28.775 LL_I W [61502:WhatsApp Worker #6] mediafileutils/getfilefrommediastore/timer/mark/file searched: 100
2021-11-30 17:48:28.779 LL_W W [61502:WhatsApp Worker #6] mediafileutils/getfilefrommediastore/file-not-found; uri=content://media/external_primary/file/14344; exception=java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EFAULT (Bad address)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EFAULT (Bad address)
    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:344)
    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:231)
    at X.31v.A0F(:387401)
    at X.3KQ.A06(:449668)
    at X.0Mu.A09(:89132)
    at X.3TG.doInBackground(:488495)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at X.03A.run(:32737)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

2021-11-30 17:48:28.806 LL_I W [2:main] redraw:1080 | 1955
2021-11-30 17:48:28.838 LL_I W [2:main] app/send-presence-subscription jid=9749@s.whatsapp.net
2021-11-30 17:48:28.838 LL_I W [2:main] MessageClient/sendXmpp; type=12
### end stack trace
```

EDIT: additional logcat

2021-12-15 01:03:37.190 5053-14983/? E/MediaProvider: Couldn't find file: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyFolderName/bikeev.pdf
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyFolderName/bikeev.pdf not found while calculating redaction ranges: No item at content://media/external_primary/file
at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.getRedactionRangesForFuse(MediaProvider.java:8041)
at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.onFileOpenForFuse(MediaProvider.java:8257)
2021-12-15 01:03:37.191 20536-20536/? E/om.whatsapp.w4: Invalid ID 0x00000000.

anyone knows how can I solve this issue

Comment: Probably you have to add a flag grant read uri permission.

Comment: @blackapps yes I tried that, I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: I still dont see a flag.

Answer (score 0):

Change putExtra:

```
putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", file))
```